# Java EE/ JPA @PersistenceContext(unitName = ) doesn't inject Hibernate entity manager implementation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Currently, I learn the Java EE JPA specification. I am using Hibernate as JPA implementation. And I have the next issue:
I have a simple entity

```
@Entity
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String title;

private String description;

private Float unitCost;

public Book() {

}
// getters and setters
}
```

And a simple Service:

```
public class BookService {

@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "book_store")
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void create(Book book) {
    entityManager.persist(book);
    entityManager.flush();
}
}
```

The persistence.xml has next view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
         version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="book_store">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.example.jpatest1.Book</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
    value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" 
    value="somePasss"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sammy"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book_store? 
    autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
    value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And I don't understand why the Hibernate Session don't inject into BookService. In book service as EntityManager I got org.jboss.as.TransactionScopedEntityManager instead of SessionImpl from Hibernate. Why using @PersistenceContext(unitName = ) I don't get Hibernate EntityManager implementation?
Also, I pin link on github: [link on code source](https://github.com/stasiukevych/jpa-test)

Comment: The specifications do not dictate what EntityManager implementation class you get, and the container is giving you its own wrapper implementation to handle lifecycle operations for you. If you need specific implementation classes, you must use the unwrap methods to get at them.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the object field `entityManager` is `EntityManager`, so you get injected what you declared in that field.

To get session from `EntityManager`, you can try this:

`Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);`